# Sending operators to mysql statement

Tags: mysql, perl, cgi

I've been stuck on this for about three hours and searched the web, all I need to happen is for a popup_menu to send an operator to a mysql statement, here is what I have so far.

```
$sqltest=$dbh->prepare("SELECT Time, Date, Event FROM Events WHERE Date ? ?");
$sqltest->execute(param('1'),(param('4')."-".param('3')."-".param('2')));

popup_menu({-values=>["<",">","="], -name=>'1'})
```

The code works perfectly if I remove the first question mark and replace it with an operator, so all other parameters are working fine, its just having a problems sending the operator.

Cheers all.

Comment: You can't send an operator as a parameter. You'll have to inject it directly into the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind values to parameters.  An operator is not a value, so you can't bind it to a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, you cannot bind an operator. There's a programming approach if you don't want to build your query strings dynamically:

```
%sqltest = (
    '<' => $dbh->prepare("SELECT Time, Date, Event FROM Events WHERE Date < ?"),
    '=' => $dbh->prepare("SELECT Time, Date, Event FROM Events WHERE Date = ?"), 
    '>' => $dbh->prepare("SELECT Time, Date, Event FROM Events WHERE Date > ?")
);
$sqltest{param(1)}->execute( param('4')."-".param('3')."-".param('2') );
```